# Fixing type inference for higher kinded type

Tags: scala, type-inference, higher-kinded-types

Ok, so I have this wonderfully simple setup:

```
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]]

trait Elem[S <: Sys[S]]

trait AttrElem[S <: Sys[S]] {
  type E <: Elem[S]

  def attributes: Any
  def element: E
}
```

And a factory:

```
object Factory {
  def apply[S <: Sys[S], E1 <: Elem[S]](
    elem: E1): AttrElem[S] { type E = E1 } = new Impl(elem)

  private class Impl[S <: Sys[S], E1 <: Elem[S]](val element: E1) 
    extends AttrElem[S] { 

    type E = E1

    def attributes = 1234
  }
}
```

Now in practice the f*** Scala type inference breaks down:

```
def test[S <: Sys[S]](elem: Elem[S]): Unit = {
  Factory(elem)
}

<console>:62: error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,Elem[S]] do not conform
  to method apply's type parameter bounds [S <: Sys[S],E1 <: Elem[S]]
             Factory(elem)
             ^
```

---

So my next attempt is existential types:

```
object Factory {
  def apply[S <: Sys[S], E1[~] <: Elem[~] forSome { type ~ <: Sys[~] }](
    elem: E1[S]): AttrElem[S] { type E = E1[S] } = new Impl(elem)

  private class Impl[S <: Sys[S], E1[~] <: Elem[~] forSome { type ~ <: Sys[~] }](
    val element: E1[S]) extends AttrElem[S] { 

    type E = E1[S]

    def attributes = 1234
  }
}
```

This gives me this following lovely message:

```
<console>:62: error: inferred kinds of the type arguments (S,E1[S]) do not 
  conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type S,type E1) in
  class Impl.
E1[S]'s type parameters do not match type E1's expected parameters:
type E1 has one type parameter, but type E1 (in class Impl) has one
               elem: E1[S]): AttrElem[S] { type E = E1[S] } = new Impl(elem)
                                                              ^
```

"type E1 has one type parameter, but type E1 has one" -- huh?

---

**Question: How can I define the factory's `apply` method to infer the types?**

Comment: Is `f***` an abbreviation for `f-bounded polymorphic`?

Comment: It's a type formalism called System F*** (triple-star)

Comment: Can you describe what are you trying to achieve in "human words". Too hard for me to infer the meaning of Sys/Elem/AttrElem.

Comment: I want to be able to write `Factory(elem)` when `elem` is fully known, a sub-type of `Elem[S]`. Without having to type `Factory[S, SomeSubtypeOfElem[S]](elem)`. In other words, I want to use the advertised feature of _type-inference_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following "redundancy" seems to satisfy the compiler:

```
def apply[S <: Sys[S], E1 <: Elem[S]](elem: E1 with Elem[S]): 
  AttrElem[S] { type E = E1 } = ...
```

That is, adding `with Elem[S]`. It looks like a needless deficiency of the Scala compiler to not infer `S` from `E1 <: Elem[S]` where `Elem` is invariant in `S`.

Or am I missing a crucial bit?

Comment: Here is another instance of the same problem: https://gist.github.com/ScrapCodes/10713689